# Click on dynamic dropdown element with selenium and python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to click on dropdown options using selenium and python. The problem is that the dropdown values are different each time I open the browser therefore, i can not use the HTML tags from the webpage.

I'm wondering if there's any way of clicking the values?
I tried to use this line of code using answered provided by Sers in this case as an example [How to select/click in a dropdown content using selenium chromewebdriver / python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545683/how-to-select-click-in-a-dropdown-content-using-selenium-chromewebdriver-pytho)  but I'm not sure how should I change/compose the class here.

```
att4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.CLASS_NAME, f"div.awsui-select-option awsui-select-option-selectable[title='{l}']"))).click()

l is for each option in my dropdown, I need to click on each of them
```

[image]

Comment: Id value seems to be static. Can't you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong, non-stable locator.
Try this:

```
att4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-value='Bambino']"))).click()
```

Or

```
att4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Bambino']"))).click()
```